# Tokbox camera-filter API Issue

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

I am using tokbox-camera-filter api but this API already has an issue. When you change browser tab it removes video stream of publisher and when you come back on same tab it adds video stream.

Please check below link: https://aullman.github.io/opentok-camera-filters/

Open this link on two separate tab and then you can check it by changing browser tabs.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not officially supported by Tokbox so they(Tokbox) will not provide any support to you regarding this issue but you can submit your query on github from where you get this code or API.

Comment: Got the same answer from tokbox support.

Comment: Yeah, I am facing same problem too.

Comment: Now I am waiting for response from support (github).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that it's using a requestAnimationFrame call to draw the image. https://github.com/aullman/opentok-camera-filters/blob/master/src/filterTask.js#L24

requestAnimationFrame doesn't run when the tab or window is in the background. You could try replacing that with a setTimeout which still runs but it probably won't perform as well.

Comment: Thanks @Adam but what should I do to run it continuous when browser tab is changed.

Comment: Is there any way to run it in background also.

Comment: Like I said, you could try using setTimeout instead of requestAnimationFrame. Webworkers might work as well.